# Mavericks Open Directory: a user can't open or modify files he's created

Tags: macos, user-account, open-directory

The OS X server & clients are on 10.9.5.

I've got a client who's had some issues, various corruptions, etc..  I had to re-create the entire user, and in doing so, have some permissions issues.

The user is working now. If he creates a file (say in MS Word), he can save it. **But** if he closes it, he cannot reopen it or save it again!

I'm assuming that I need to change flags of some sort on this user, though I'm unsure what, where, or how.   I've not resorted to 'going nuclear' with chmod on the user folder, as I'd like to maintain a semblance of consistency here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the client accounts network accounts or local ones?

Comment: network accounts (Open directory)

Comment: with local homes or network based home?

Comment: The home folders are all on the server (network).  The users are network.

Comment: Found it.... faulty network cable - random apps locking up led me thru a stack of tests...  replaced the cable and all is well!!